# How to remove controller from grails programmatically?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, searchable, searchable-plugin

Im having some conflicts with the Searchable plugin.

I have a filter which fetches the controller in question in the before phase. It fetches the requested controller by finding the first controller that has the same name as controllerName which is a property available in grails filters.

however, my problem is that the Searchable plugin has its own SearchableController, and i myself have made my own version of the SearchableController. The effect of this is that i have two classes with the same name that would match controllerName in my find logic.

```
    controller = grailsApplication.controllerClasses.find { c ->
        c.logicalPropertyName == controllerName
    }
```

Can i somehow remove the SearchableController that comes with the plugin? What are my options?

Comment: Can you not put your SearchableController in a different namespace for the purpose of differentiation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this could help you:

http://grails.org/Searchable+Plugin+-+SearchableController+and+view

I found an existing post on this topic:
[Disable grails Searchable plugin default search page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170207/disable-grails-searchable-plugin-default-search-page)

Answer (score -1):

I worked around the issue by renaming my SearchableController class to SearchController. Don't like workarounds tho...